# How to switch from one page to another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to switch from one page to another. I've tried it out with a function and also tried it with eventlistener but it's not working. Please help me to find the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/geomatric-logo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="">
                <a class="navbar-brand fs-1">Interactive</a>
                <p class="fs-4">Geometry Genius</p>
              </div>
              <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                <button onclick="pageSwitch()" id="home-button" class="btn btn-primary px-md-4" type="submit">Blog</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src=""></script>

    <script>

        function pageSwitch() {
            window.location.href = './blog.html'
        }

        document.getElementById('home-button').onclick = function () {
            window.location.href = './blog.html'
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the problem is that the Button is placed in a form and its type is set to **submit**. this combination forces the button to act like a form submitting so the redirect is being canceled. try one of these solutions:

1. remove the form tag (not suggested to care about the html syntax)
2. change the type of button `type="button"`

Comment: Good. You may check the answer as accepted if that was the best solution. @MostafaFerdaousNayeem